# Suppose a particular sound wave momentarily exerts an extra pressure of 10^-4 atm upon a microphone diaphragm

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, dimensional-analysis

Suppose a particular sound wave momentarily exerts an extra pressure of $10^{-4}~ \text{atm}$ upon a microphone diaphragm that has an area of $1~ \text{cm}^2$.  What total force in newtons does this make on the diaphragm?

Here's the process I've tried so far:

```
Pressure: 10^-4 atm
Area:     .0001 m^2

1 atm = 101325 n/m^2

.0001 atm = 10.1325 n/m^2

1 m^2 = 10,000 cm^2

10.1325 n/m^2 * 10,000 cm^2/1 m^2 = 101325 n/cm^2
101325 n/cm^2 = 1.01325x10^5 newtons
```

But for some reason my textbook is telling me that the answer is $1.01325\times 10^-3\text{ N}$.  Where's my mistake?

I have a feeling it has to do with my conversion of $1 \text{ m}^2$ to $10,000 \text{ cm}^2$.  Should I be converting $1~\text{m}$ to $100~\text{cm}$ instead?  This would fix the problem, but the units would be wrong.  I've done the dimensional analysis and it still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the homework-and-exercises tag.

Comment: I updated your post to use mathjax. It makes it easier for others to understand your question.  Here's a [Mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

> 10.1325 n/m^2 * 10,000 cm^2/1 m^2 = 101325 n/cm^2

Let's look at what you're saying: On a $1~\text{m}^2$ area, there is a force of approx. $10~\text{N}$.  But then when you look at the force on a *much smaller* area, of $1~\text{cm}^2$, the force is $10000$ times larger.  This should ring an alarm bell to you.  The pressure is ultimately coming from collisions with air molecules, so a smaller area should mean fewer collisions, and hence smaller pressure.  However this expression is predicting the opposite.

Let's say we have pressure in $\text{N}/\text{m}^2$, and we do want it in $\text{N}/\text{cm}^2$. We're looking for the factor such that
$$A\frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}^2} = \frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}^2}.$$
We can just treat this as fractions, and we can identify $A=\frac{\text{m}^2}{\text{cm}^2}$.  You multiplied yours the other way round.

Try correcting this mistake and see if it gets you to the correct answer.  (PS check your book again, I think it should be $1.01325\times10^{-3}~\text{N}$.

Finally, it's always good in physics problems to try and think about the situation.  1 Newton is approximately the force you'll feel from gravity pulling down on an apple.  The answer of $1.01325\times10^{3}~\text{N}$ is suggesting the weight of 1000 apples per square centimetre, as the effect of a sound wave.  That can't be right!

Comment: I did mean 10^-3 N rather than 10^3.  Thank you for the explanation.